# Different results onresize and DOM ready for the same function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is suppose to center the element, it works perfectly on resize but not when DOM is first ready. I have to resize the window to get desired results. I can't figure out what was causing this...It is the same function.

```
        $(document).ready(center);
        $(window).on('resize', center);

        function center(){
            $('#vid').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'left' : '50%',
                'top' : '50%',
                'margin-left' : -$('#vid').width()/2,
                'margin-top' : -$('#vid').height()/2
            });
        }
```

Comment: I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4g11zaoz/ and can't see your problem!

Comment: I'm so confused right now because when I use same code I get different results in jsfiddle... now the it doesn't center on resize either. but this is the closest I could get to replicating what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/4g11zaoz/6/

Comment: @user2517605 - please make sure to add the javascript library into the `<head>` tag.

Comment: It seems to be the initial calculation of the video width is larger than it actually is causing the centering mishap... I'm not sure why at... but I spent hours trying to fix a very simple thing.